# Get category link to a posts list in single.php in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

We know that `single.php` in Wordpress is inside the loop so I can directly use `the_title()` or `the_permalink()` without having to create a custom query.

I am doing that already, but on top of it, I have a sidebar that displays the latest posts (custom post type) with their titles, links and categories.

I am able to retrieve all their related infor except the category link.

The code I have now returns category `uncategorized` for all the posts even though they are each in a specific category.

This is the custom query that I'm using which is fetching posts from a custom post type `cards` inside `single.php`

Notice `$categories = get_categories();` - the foreach loop displays the following URL for all posts which is simply not true.

`http://localhost/wonderhive/category/uncategorized/`

How can I fix that and retrieve the correct category URL? Since I'm already retrieving the correct category name.

```
<?php
            $queryObject = new WP_Query( 'post_type=cards&posts_per_page=-1' );
            if ($queryObject->have_posts()) {

                while ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
                    $queryObject->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="vista bg-black p-12 h-60 black">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('small'); ?>" alt="gian" class="f-left foto r-100 ">
                        <div class="f-left">
                            <h5 class="gray2">
                                <?php
                                $thetitle = $post->post_title;
                                $getlength = strlen($thetitle);
                                $thelength = 45;
                                echo substr($thetitle, 0, $thelength);
                                if ($getlength > $thelength) echo "...";
                                ?>
                            </h5>
                    </a>
                        <h6>
                            <?php
                            $categories = get_categories();
                            foreach ($categories as $cat) {
                                $category_link = get_category_link($cat->cat_ID);
                                echo $category_link;
                            }
                            ?>
                            <a href="">
                                <?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'categories');
                                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                                    echo $term->name;
                                }
                                ?>
                            </a>
                        </h6>
                    </div>
                    <span class="f-right"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
                </div>
                <?php }
            }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$categories = get_the_category()` instead of `$categories = get_categories()`. This function will get the categories for the current post instead.

For more information see the [WordPress Codex on get_the_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/). Good luck!